# What is the advantage of using favicon middleware for Express / Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, favicon

I want to add a favicon to my website (written in JavaScript with Node.JS & Express). Resources on the internet point towards using the favicon-serve middleware. The Express generator also includes this middleware.

At the moment I'm serving static files with the following line of code.

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

So I dropped `favicon.ico` in the `/public` folder and the favicon works like it should (without using the favicon-serve middleware).

So my question is: why would one want to use the favicon-middleware? Why not just put it in a public folder with other static resources (.css / .png / ...)?

EDIT: I'm getting some downvotes, sorry if this is too much of a "RTM"-question, but as a beginner (in JavaScript / Node.js) it's easy to get lost in the external modules. It's hard to find resources for Node.js that aren't "install this module, learn to use this module, done" - as a beginner I often want know how someone would solve a problem without another external module, even if you end up using the module anyway.

Comment: what if you don't have static resources?

Comment: Isn't the favicon a static resource itself? Why would someone use middleware if the functionality is already short/easy to use in express?

Comment: `Isn't the favicon a static resource itself?` - what if you don't have static resources

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't understand what you're trying to say. My argument is that when you have no static resources in a project, and you're adding a favicon.ico, the favicon.ico would be the (first) static resource in your project. So why not serve it as a static resource?

Comment: sorry, I thought perhaps using the `favicon-middleware` meant you didn't need `app.use(express.static('./public'));` - since (if it's the middleware I know of) - `app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))` ... see, no need for `express.static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered by [the documentation for the module](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon):

> - User agents request favicon.ico frequently and indiscriminately, so you may wish to exclude these requests from your logs by using this
>     middleware before your logger middleware.
> - This module caches the icon in memory to improve performance by skipping disk access.
> - This module provides an ETag based on the contents of the icon, rather than file system properties.
> - This module will serve with the most compatible Content-Type.

Comment: So in a nutshell, the main advantages are for logging (more precise: not logging) and caching purposes?

Comment: This module improves the app performance (a little bit), the middlewares are running in the order of declaration, so when you use this module and declared it before `static` middleware, it will be called first and returned cashed favicon.